# Deserialise JSON with random key

Tags: c#, json

I am accessing an API which is returning JSon in the format:

```
{"status":1,"complete":1,"list":{"293352541":{"item_id":"293352541","fave":"0"},"247320106":{"item_id":"247320106","fave":"0"},"291842735":{"item_id":"291842735","fave":"0"} .....
```

The problem I am having is with **the number before the item_id tag**. It is breaking any attempt I make at deserialising as I cannot represent this random integer in an object that I deserialise in to.

I would expect this number to be, for example, the word "Item", so that it is key representing the enclosed object, but having this number means I cannot make an object representation of the JSon.

So

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string complete { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject> list { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string fave { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
 var items = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(jsontext);
```

dersialises, but items.list is empty.

Also,

```
dynamic result = JSon.Parse(jsontext);
```

works, but I cannot deserialise or access the list of items in a nice way.

Is there any way to do this? thanks

Comment: Possible remove the string if you do not need it? Remove the string then parse the json into your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't require predefined types to deserialize into, you can do this with [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (also available with nuget). For instance:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(data);
var sense = jObj["list"]
    .Select(x => (JProperty)x)
    .Select(p => new { 
                   propName = p.Name,
                   itemId = p.Value["item_id"],
                   fave = p.Value["fave"]});
```