# Convert json string to CLR Types

Tags: c#, json

I have following json stirng

```
{
"api_version" : 2 ,
"lang" : "en_US",
"hotels" :
[
{
"hotel_id" : 258705 ,
"desc" : "The Hotel Commonwealth stands above the Kenmore Square \"T\" subway station in Boston, Mass. Fenway Park is located two blocks away, while the shops along Newbury Street are three blocks from the hotel.",
"amenities" : ["RESTAURANT","NON_SMOKING"],
"room_types" :
{
"Fenway Room" :
{
"url" : "http://www.partnersite.com/hotel_commonwealth/fenway_room",
"desc" : "One king bed with pillowtop mattress, Frette Italian linens, down bedding, multiple pillows. View of Fenway Park."
},
"Commonwealth Room" :
{
"url" : "http://www.partnersite.com/hotel_commonwealth/commonwealth_room",
"desc" : "One king bed with pillowtop mattress, Frette Italian linens, down bedding, multiple pillows. View of Commonwealth Avenue."
}
}
}
]
}
```

and I have created following poco classes.I am able to deserialize the above string using NewtonSoft.

```
internal class FenwayRoom
    {    

    }

    internal class CommonwealthRoom
    {

    }

    internal class RoomTypes
    {

        [JsonProperty("Fenway Room")]
        public FenwayRoom FenwayRoom { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Commonwealth Room")]
        public CommonwealthRoom CommonwealthRoom { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Hotel
    {


    }

}
```

Now the problem is that for every roomtype I have to create a septate class.Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: I describe how to do it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673555/14357

Comment: You shouldn't need POCOs for each instance of a type... but this JSON format you have above doesn't lend itself particularly well to map directly in to POCOs.  Also, consider using a JSON parser like `ServiceStack.Text` and then you don't have to adorn properties etc with attributes.  Can you change the JSON format?

Comment: @Moo-Juice:We can not change json format

Answer (score 1):

The properties per room appear to be the same, you just need to introduce a single `Room` class e.g.

```
public class Room
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RoomTypes
{
    [JsonProperty("Fenway Room")]
    public Room FenwayRoom { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Commonwealth Room")]
    public Room CommonWealthRoom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already using this.If I add new room type then I have to add one more proerty in roomtypes

Comment: @muski unfortunately your JSON data dictates that in order to have a concrete class type with automatic mapping the model has to be *exactly* the same as the data. The `room_types` property is a complex object with room properties, it's not a list so it makes sense that you have to update the model accordingly. By introducing a single `Room` class you at least don't need to introduce a separate class *per room*, you just need to add the property in for serialization. Alternatively you can go down the route of manual mapping (see @spender linked answer).

Comment: +1... Might also be nicer to Alias away `url` to `Url`, et al.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I actually had that in and took it back out, will add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use automated tools like this:

[JSON TO CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/)

[JSONPACK](http://jsonpack.com/)

Comment: tools are generating same class as posted on question